# Al ejecutar un comando remoto por ssh la variable es recortada

Tags: bash, ssh

Quiero ejecutar el siguiente comando desde un script.

public_ley  contiene una clave publica que empieza con ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2 , pero cuando lo por ssh ejecuto el comando no pasa todo el contenido de la variable, como si le hiciera un trim y solo contiene ssh-rsa y recorta el resto, alquien sabe como hacer para que le pase todo el string?

publickey es un archivo local que contine la clave publica, cabe aclarar
que si lo ejecuto local, funciona, quiero decir, echo $public_ley contiene 
todo el string, el problema es cuando lo ejecuto por ssh.

```
public_key=`cat publickey`

ssh $username@$p  -i $key_path/$key_name "sudo bash /tmp/update-sshkey.sh $username $public_key"
```

el script update-sshkey.sh toma como parametros el nombre de usuario y la key la cual asigno a dos variables con $1 y $2 , $2 contiene solo ssh-rsa y no el resto de la clave

Tambien probé esto:

```
command=`ssh -t $username@$p  -i /root/.ssh/$key_name  "sudo bash /tmp/update-sshkey.sh $username $public_key"`
```

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

podrias intentar de esta forma:

```
ssh -t $username@$p  -i /root/.ssh/$key_name "sudo bash /tmp/update-sshkey.sh $username $public_key"
```

Comment: Hola Bryro, gracias por responder ^^. Para mejorar la respuesta podrias explicar qué tiene mal la pregunta y cómo tu respuesta da solución al problema. Mira [answer] para mejorarla, Un saludo

Comment: Hola, hace lo mismo, recorta todo a partir de ssh-rsa,

Comment: No veo la forma de que pase todo el string de la clave, ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAAgQDh1W+l7FFaaxiTBYiihiZhKNV3BPCO6X35F6zrpyMPWFqYffM0Dqd+UO3Pk8Mm8/Dffs+jeT0Oo+FSlCvcH8T8xKShW3FmFylUrCJin8do/Cf8Hzdw2a4Roxueg8fOBmzH4IOUkHNdRwQjmFrqoQ99GYuzvrZTH3oTUO9NwhBsbQ== usuario@servidor

Comment: Encontre que bash -c sirve para expandir la variables, ahora esto me funciona en parte ssh  $username@$p  -i /root/.ssh/$key_name  " 'sudo bash -c  /tmp/update-sshkey.sh $username $public_key ' " entre comillas simples y dobles mas -c , pero ahora tengo otro problema, no me toma las variables $1 $2 que le paso como parametro al script. si lo ejecuto al script en el servidor remoto  con -c , si hago un echo $1 o $2 no muestra nada, sin -c en bash si me mustra las dos variables.

Comment: En resumen para hacerlo mas claro, si ejecuto el script con bash -c y dentro del script hago un echo de una variable no me funciona, sin el -c si hace el echo del contenido.